# Is there a package for R or Python that will generate rectangular pie charts?

Tags: software-development, open-source, python

Normally, pie charts are circular and each piece of data is shown as a slice of a whole.

However, for some purposes, it makes more sense to display the same kind of data as a rectangle divided up with vertical lines, with each horizontal "slice" of the rectangle representing a piece of the data.

```
Bicycle,25%
Plane,25%
Car,50%


________________________________________________
|_Bicycle__|____Plane___|_________Car___________|
```

Note that the intent of the above depiction is to have one long rectangle cut into 3 pieces. Two are `25%` of the total rectangle and one is `50%` of the rectangle.

Is there a package in Python or R that has can generate such a "rectangular" pie chart?

Answer (score 1):

The term you are probably looking for is "mosaic chart" (alternatively, a "treemap").

A search through SO yields [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868799/how-to-output-a-chart-from-nielsen).

In `R`:

```
 require("vcd")
 data(HairEyeColor)
 mosaic(HairEyeColor, shade = TRUE)
```

[image: First pic]

[image: Second pic]